# Method not working correctly in the subclass when it does in the superclass?

Tags: java, inheritance

I made a number guessing program and I'm trying to input it into a subclass. The number guessing program is successful in its own class but when I run my the class that it's not originally from, then for some reason the same number (0) is randomly generated? Here is the superclass code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class GuessTheNumber {

    static int randomNum;
    static int guess;

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        random();
        do {
            guess();
        }
        while (guess != randomNum);

    }

    public static void random() {
        // Math.Random() - 1s and 0s
        randomNum = (int) (Math.random() * 11);
    }

    public static void guess() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a guess: ");
        guess = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Your guess is " + guess + ".");
        if (guess == randomNum)
            System.out.println("Your guess is correct! Yay!");
        else if (guess < randomNum)
            System.out.println("Guess higher.");
        else if (guess > randomNum)
            System.out.println("Guess lower.");
    }

}
```

Here is the code for the subclass where the random generator does not work:

```
import java.util.*;

public class GuessTheNumber {

    static int randomNum;
    static int guess;

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        random();
        do {
            guess();
        }
        while (guess != randomNum);

    }

    public static void random() {
        // Math.Random() - 1s and 0s
        randomNum = (int) (Math.random() * 11);
    }

    public static void guess() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a guess: ");
        guess = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Your guess is " + guess + ".");
        if (guess == randomNum)
            System.out.println("Your guess is correct! Yay!");
        else if (guess < randomNum)
            System.out.println("Guess higher.");
        else if (guess > randomNum)
            System.out.println("Guess lower.");
    }

}
```

I'm not sure if I somehow altered the random number generator to not work anymore or if it's because I did not correctly execute putting the superclass' methods into the subclass.
(Also I'm sorry if there's any mistakes in terminology/grammar or if this question's unclear. It's clearly late. Thanks.)

Comment: I don't see any "subclass" in your code

Comment: I don't see a sub-class. Also, you're using `Math.random()` so how would your inheritance chain effect it?

Comment: You posted the same code twice, as far as I can see. Please have a look again at you question.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `rand.nextInt()` instead of `randomNum = (int) (Math.random()`. That is,

```
// nextInt is normally exclusive of the top value,
// so add 1 to make it inclusive
int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1)*11
```

, should work fine.

Comment: The question needs an edit, that much is obvious. If you would like to edit the question to fit what OP is asking, be my guest.

Comment: if OP says that superclass code work fine and subclass's not and he posted only superclass then how can you suggest or give an answer on wrong question

Answer (score -1):

We have to call a method of super class in the sub class with help of super keyword and sigiture of the method is also same.